# OpenGL cube and pyramid

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math

I have this OpenGL code the draws a cube and pyramid. However, this program rotates the pyramid and cube together. I am tasked with only making the cube itself move not both objects at the same time. I know for this to happen I have to implement shaders for both. I'm not sure how to go about implementing both of the shaders at once. Any tips?

```
/*
This program demonstrates simple lighting.
A pyramid is lighted by a point light and can be rotated by mouse.

Ying Zhu
Georgia State University

October 2016
*/

// GLEW header
#include <GL/glew.h> // This must appear before freeglut.h

// Freeglut header
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// GLM header files
#include <glm/glm.hpp> 

#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> 
// #include <glm/gtx/transform2.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_access.hpp>
// #include <glm/gtx/projection.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_inverse.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> 

// C++ header files
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) ((GLvoid *) offset)

// VBO buffer IDs
GLuint vertexArrayBufferID = 0;
GLuint normalArrayBufferID = 0;
GLuint cubePosition = 0;
GLuint cubeElements = 0;

GLuint program; // shader program ID

// Shader variable IDs
GLint vPos; // vertex attribute: position
GLint normalID; // vertex attribute: normal

GLint mvpMatrixID; // uniform variable: model, view, projection matrix
GLint modelMatrixID; // uniform variable: model, view matrix
GLint normalMatrixID; // uniform variable: normal matrix for transforming normals
GLint lightSourcePositionID; // uniform variable: for lighting calculation
GLint diffuseLightProductID; // uniform variable: for lighting calculation
GLint ambientID;
GLint attenuationAID;
GLint attenuationBID;
GLint attenuationCID;

// Transformation matrices
mat4 projMatrix;
mat4 mvpMatrix;
mat4 modelMatrix;
mat4 viewMatrix;
mat3 normalMatrix;  // Normal matrix for transforming normals

// Light parameters
vec4 lightSourcePosition = vec4(0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 diffuseMaterial = vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 diffuseLightIntensity = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 ambient = vec4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
float attenuationA = 1.0f;
float attenuationB = 0.2f;
float attenuationC = 0.0f;

vec4 diffuseLightProduct;

// Camera parameters
vec3 eyePosition = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);
vec3 lookAtCenter = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 upVector = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
float fieldOfView = 30.0f;
float nearPlane = 0.1f;
float farPlane = 1000.0f;

// Mouse controlled rotation angles
float rotateX = 0;
float rotateY = 0;

struct VertexData {
    GLfloat vertex[3];

    VertexData(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) {
        vertex[0] = x; vertex[1] = y; vertex[2] = z;
    }
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialize vertex arrays and VBOs
void prepareVBOs() {
    // Define a 3D pyramid. 
    GLfloat vertices[][4] = {
        {1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, // face 1
        {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f},
        {1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f},
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 2
        {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 3
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        {-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 4
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // face 5
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, // face 6
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f }
    };

    GLfloat normals[][4] = {
        {0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, // normal 1
        {0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        {0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        {0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, // normal 2
        { 0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        { 0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        {-0.0f, 0.4472f, 0.8944f, 1.0f}, // normal 3
        { -0.0f, 0.4472f, 0.8944f, 1.0f },
        { -0.0f, 0.4472f, 0.8944f, 1.0f },
        {-0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, // normal 4
        { -0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        { -0.8944f, 0.4472f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        {0.0f, 0.4472f, -0.8944f, 1.0f}, // normal 5
        { 0.0f, 0.4472f, -0.8944f, 1.0f },
        { 0.0f, 0.4472f, -0.8944f, 1.0f },
        { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, // normal 6
        { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }
    };

    // Cube positioins 
    VertexData vertexData[] = {
        VertexData(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), /* Index 0 */
        VertexData(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), /* Index 1 */
        VertexData(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), /* Index 2 */
        VertexData(0.0, 1.0, 1.0), /* Index 3 */
        VertexData(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), /* Index 4 */
        VertexData(1.0, 0.0, 1.0), /* Index 5 */
        VertexData(1.0, 1.0, 0.0), /* Index 6 */
        VertexData(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), /* Index 7 */
    };

    // Cube elements
    GLubyte indices[] = {
        4, 5, 7, // +X face
        4, 7, 6,
        0, 2, 3, // ‐X face
        0, 3, 1,
        2, 6, 7, // +Y face
        2, 7, 3,
        0, 1, 5, // ‐Y face
        0, 5, 4,
        0, 4, 6, // +Z face
        0, 6, 2,
        1, 3, 7, // ‐Z face
        1, 7, 5
    };
    // Get an unused buffer object name. Required after OpenGL 3.1. 
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArrayBufferID);

    // If it's the first time the buffer object name is used, create that buffer. 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBufferID);

    // Allocate memory for the active buffer object. 
    // 1. Allocate memory on the graphics card for the amount specified by the 2nd parameter.
    // 2. Copy the data referenced by the third parameter (a pointer) from the main memory to the 
    //    memory on the graphics card. 
    // 3. If you want to dynamically load the data, then set the third parameter to be NULL. 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &normalArrayBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalArrayBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(normals), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &cubePosition);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubePosition);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData),
        vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeElements);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeElements);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices),
        indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Print out the output of the shader compiler
void printLog(GLuint obj)
{
    int infologLength = 0;
    char infoLog[1024];

    if (glIsShader(obj)) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(obj, 1024, &infologLength, infoLog);
    }
    else {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(obj, 1024, &infologLength, infoLog);
    }

    if (infologLength > 0) {
        cout << infoLog;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void prepareShaders() {
    // Vertex shader source code
    // A point light source is implemented. 
    // For simplicity, only the ambient and diffuse components are implemented. 
    // The lighting is calculated in world space, not in camera space. 
    const char* vSource = {
        "#version 330\n"
        "in vec4 vPos;"
        "in vec4 normal;"

        "uniform mat4x4 mvpMatrix;"
        "uniform mat4x4 modelMatrix;"
        "uniform mat3x3 normalMatrix;"
        "uniform vec4 lightSourcePosition;"
        "uniform vec4 diffuseLightProduct;"
        "uniform vec4 ambient;"
        "uniform float attenuationA;"
        "uniform float attenuationB;"
        "uniform float attenuationC;"
        "out vec4 color;"

        "void main() {"
        "   gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vPos;"
        // Transform the vertex position to the world space. 
        "   vec4 transformedVertex = modelMatrix * vPos;"
        // Transform the normal vector to the world space. 
        "   vec3 transformedNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal.xyz);"
        // Light direction
        "   vec3 lightVector = normalize(transformedVertex.xyz - lightSourcePosition.xyz);"
        // Distance between the light source and vertex
        "   float dist = distance(lightSourcePosition.xyz, transformedVertex.xyz);"
        // Attenuation factor
        "   float attenuation = 1.0f / (attenuationA + (attenuationB * dist) + (attenuationC * dist * dist));"
        // Calculate the diffuse component of the lighting equation.
        "   vec4 diffuse = attenuation * (max(dot(transformedNormal, lightVector), 0.0) * diffuseLightProduct);"
        // Combine the ambient component and diffuse component. 
        "   color = ambient + diffuse;"
        "}"
    };

    // Fragment shader source code
    const char* fSource = {
        "#version 330\n"
        "in vec4 color;"
        "out vec4 fragColor;"
        "void main() {"
        "   fragColor = color;"
        "}"
    };

    // Declare shader IDs
    GLuint vShader, fShader;

    // Create empty shader objects
    vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Attach shader source code the shader objects
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fSource, NULL);

    // Compile shader objects
    glCompileShader(vShader);
    printLog(vShader);

    glCompileShader(fShader);
    printLog(fShader);

    // Create an empty shader program object
    program = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach vertex and fragment shaders to the shader program
    glAttachShader(program, vShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fShader);

    // Link the shader program
    glLinkProgram(program);
    printLog(program);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Retrieve the IDs of the shader variables. Later we will
// use these IDs to pass data to the shaders. 
void getShaderVariableLocations(GLuint shaderProgram) {

    // Retrieve the ID of a vertex attribute, i.e. position
    vPos = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPos");
    normalID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "normal");

    mvpMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix");

    modelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modelMatrix");
    normalMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "normalMatrix");

    lightSourcePositionID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightSourcePosition");
    diffuseLightProductID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "diffuseLightProduct");
    ambientID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ambient");

    attenuationAID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "attenuationA");
    attenuationBID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "attenuationB");
    attenuationCID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "attenuationC");
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void setShaderVariables() {
    // value_ptr is a glm function
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(mvpMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(modelMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(normalMatrix));

    glUniform4fv(lightSourcePositionID, 1, value_ptr(lightSourcePosition));
    glUniform4fv(diffuseLightProductID, 1, value_ptr(diffuseLightProduct));
    glUniform4fv(ambientID, 1, value_ptr(ambient));
    glUniform1f(attenuationAID, attenuationA);
    glUniform1f(attenuationBID, attenuationB);
    glUniform1f(attenuationCID, attenuationC);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Set lighting related parameters
void setLightingParam() {
    diffuseLightProduct = diffuseMaterial * diffuseLightIntensity;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the model matrix. This matrix will transform the 3D object to the proper place. 
mat4 buildModelMatrix() {

    mat4 rotationXMatrix = rotate(mat4(1.0f), radians(rotateX), vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    mat4 rotationYMatrix = rotate(mat4(1.0f), radians(rotateY), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    mat4 matrix = rotationYMatrix * rotationXMatrix;

    return matrix;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void buildMatrices() {
    modelMatrix = buildModelMatrix();

    mvpMatrix = projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

    normalMatrix = column(normalMatrix, 0, vec3(modelMatrix[0][0], modelMatrix[0][1], modelMatrix[0][2]));
    normalMatrix = column(normalMatrix, 1, vec3(modelMatrix[1][0], modelMatrix[1][1], modelMatrix[1][2]));
    normalMatrix = column(normalMatrix, 2, vec3(modelMatrix[2][0], modelMatrix[2][1], modelMatrix[2][2]));

    // Use glm::inverseTranspose() to create a normal matrix, which is used to transform normal vectors. 
    normalMatrix = inverseTranspose(normalMatrix);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Handles the display event
void display()
{
    // Clear the window with the background color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    buildMatrices();

    setShaderVariables();

    // Activate the shader program
    glUseProgram(program);

    // If the buffer object already exists, make that buffer the current active one. 
    // If the buffer object name is 0, disable buffer objects. 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBufferID);

    // Associate the vertex array in the buffer object with the vertex attribute: "position"
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPos, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    // Enable the vertex attribute: "position"
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalArrayBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalID, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalID);

    // Start the shader program. Draw the object. The third parameter is the number of triangles. 
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubePosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeElements);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    // Refresh the window
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Handles the reshape event
void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    // Specify the width and height of the picture within the window
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    projMatrix = perspective(fieldOfView, (float)width / (float)height, nearPlane, farPlane);

    viewMatrix = lookAt(eyePosition, lookAtCenter, upVector);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Read mouse motion data and convert them to rotation angles. 
void passiveMotion(int x, int y) {

    rotateY = (float)x * -0.8f;
    rotateX = (float)y * -0.8f;

    // Generate a dislay event to force refreshing the window. 
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
void init() {
    prepareVBOs();

    prepareShaders();

    getShaderVariableLocations(program);

    setLightingParam();

    // Specify the background color
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Lighting Demo");

    glutReshapeWindow(800, 800);

    glewInit();

    init();

    // Register the display callback function
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    // Register the reshape callback function
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    // Register the passive mouse motion call back function
    // This function is called when the mouse moves within the window
    // while no mouse buttons are pressed. 
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotion);

    // Start the event loop
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: You have to use different model matirces. Change the model matrix (`glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(modelMatrix));`) right before the draw call.

Comment: So you're saying i should change the parameter of the value_ptr() to an indivifual modelMatrix that I would create for the cube itself?

Comment: The position and orientation of an object (mesh) is defined by the model matrix. If you want to draw different objects with different positions and/or orientations, the you have to use different model matrices. You can use the same shader, but you have to change the model matrix (`glUniformMatrix4fv`), right before you draw the object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious culprit here would be setting a single ModelMatrix for both - I can't see any logic in your code to set them independently for each object you're rendering.

Since each object has a different rotation (and presumably, unless you're planning to draw one on top of the other, a different translation), you would want to be generating / loading a different model matrix for each draw call.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use different shaders, you just need to use different model matricies. Say you have two objects in you scene something like this:

```
while (!myWindow(shouldClose))
{
    myShader.use();

    glBindVertexArray(myVao1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, x); // Draw pyramid

    glBindVertaxArray(myVao2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, x); // Draw cube
}
```

Say you want only the second model to rotate on the y axis, you could do something like this:

```
float rotationDegree = 0;
while (!myWindow(shouldClose))
{
    myShader.use();
    myShader.setMat4(glm::mat4(1.0f)) // Make sure to set it to normal matrix for the pyrmamid
    glBindVertexArray(myVao1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, x); // Draw pyramid

    glBindVertaxArray(myVao2);
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationDegree), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    rotateionDegree += 0.01;
    myShader.setMat4("model", model); // Set you model matrix in your shader.
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, x); // Draw cube
}
```